# Set authentication header in zap docker based API scan

Tags: zap

I am trying to use zap api scan in zap docker image. APIs are OIDC authenticated. Authentication is performed using "Graal.js" script and access token is set as global var using `org.zaproxy.zap.extension.script.ScriptVars.setGlobalVar("accessToken",accessToken);`

Access token is set as authorization header value using a httpSender script. In zap desktop, it is done using "Oracle Nashorn" engine. But in zap docker "Oracle Nashorn" engine is not available.

I have tried using Graal.js engine itself, but it fails with multi threading not allowed for JS engine.
What are the other ways to set the header ?

Answer (score 4):

Why not just use the authentication env vars supported natively by ZAP?

- ZAP_AUTH_HEADER_VALUE - if this is defined then its value will be added as a header to all of the requests
- ZAP_AUTH_HEADER - if this is defined then its value will be used as the header name - if it is not defined then the standard Authorization header will be used
- ZAP_AUTH_HEADER_SITE - if this is defined then the header will only be included in sites whose name includes its value

All documented on https://www.zaproxy.org/docs/authentication/handling-auth-yourself/

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply @Simon. I forgot to mention that I have couple of more header values to be set. That is the reason I chose to use httpSender script.

Comment: In that case you can use replacer rules https://www.zaproxy.org/docs/desktop/addons/replacer/ or rewrite your script in any of the other languages we support, eg jython, jruby, kotlin, zest ... we have examples for some of them on https://github.com/zaproxy/community-scripts/tree/main/httpsender - note that only zest is installed by default, the other scripting languages will need to be installed